# Connotation of "Du bist jederzeit willkommen in [Stadtname]"

Tags: connotation, politeness

A German friend said to me:

> Du bist jederzeit willkommen in [Stadtname].

I’m not sure if this is an invitation to stay at his place in that city, or does it just mean I’m welcome to hang out with him when I’m in that city. I am also reluctant to ask him this question directly.

Which of the two cases does this sentence likely mean? If it’s not clear, is there a nice way to ask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since he is a friend of yours, it is at the minimum an invitation to come visit him. Whether or not he invites you to stay at his place is not completely implicit. You could ask him for a recommendation of a place to stay, though, and see how he reacts.